# Array of bullets collision detection in slick2d

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I've created a Bullet class using vectors to draw bullets and store them in an array.
I've tried but couldn't figure out how to detect collision with these bullets.

**Here is the Bullet class:**

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    if(active) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(pos.getX()-10, pos.getY()-10, 20, 20);

        g.drawString("BulletX: "+pos.getX(), 400, 100);
        g.drawString("BulletY: "+pos.getY(), 400, 120);
    }
}

public void update(int t) {

    if(active) {
        Vector2f realSpeed = speed.copy();
        pos.add(speed.copy().scale(t/1000.0f));
        pos.add(realSpeed);

        lived += t;
        if(lived > MAX_LIFETIME) {
            active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Play class:**

I have filled the array in the init method using this code:

```
bullets = new Bullet[8];
    for(int i=0; i<bullets.length; i++) {
        bullets[i] = new Bullet();
    }
```

In the update class I've used this code to display the bullets when the player chooses to fire:

```
if(t > FIRE_RATE && gc.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE)) {
        if(player == movingUp) {
            bullets[current] = new Bullet(new Vector2f(420,295), new Vector2f(0,-1));
            current++; 
            if(current >= bullets.length) current = 0;
            t = 0;
        }
```

**Here is the player and enemy movement**

```
//up
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        player = movingUp;
        playerPositionY += delta * .3f; //moves world
        enemyPositionY += delta * .3f;
        if(playerPositionY > 273) { //collision detection
            playerPositionY -= delta * .3f;
            enemyPositionY -= delta * .3f;
        }
    }

if(enemyPositionY > shiftY) {
        enemyPositionY -= delta *.1f;
    }
    if((enemyPositionX >= 355 && enemyPositionX <= 440) && (enemyPositionY >= 230 && enemyPositionY <= 310)) {
        enemyPositionX = playerPositionX;
        enemyPositionY = playerPositionY;
        lives--;
    }
```

Can you help me understand how I can detect collisions with these bullets please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a Rectangle property to the bullets in the bullets class (initialize it before hand and update the position in the update method)?  Something like

```
bulletRectangle = new Rectangle(pos.getX(), pos.getY(), 20, 20);
```

And then create the rectangle for the player such as playerRectangle and then using the intersect function check for the collision in a loop.

```
collision = false; 
for(int i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
    if(playerRectangle.intersects(bullet[i].getBulletRectangle())){
        collision = true;
}
//perform whatever you want to happen if bullet collides with player
```

Personally, I would use an array list because you don't have to set the number of bullets to a specific number, but this should work just fine.

Comment: +1. This is how most 2D game engines/collision libraries do it.

Comment: Depending on the Speed of the bullet you might run into some issues however